# 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel. I want to read and change this excel file, after that I want to save this excel file as a new excel file. I had to change the column of the excel to a string, because in this column there were emojis. My problem is when I'm trying to saving the excel file.

The error message

```
with link or location/anchor > 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS
  force_unicode(url))
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py:931: UserWarning: Ignoring URL 'https://stackoverflow.com/...'
```

I found this code snippet, by others who had the same problem

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path+fileName, options={'strings_to_urls': False})
```

But I don't know how can I use the `writer` and my  `df['Content'] = df['Content'].astype(str)` . How can I save my excel file without an error ? Before the saving I want to give the excel file out and change it.

My code

```
import pandas as pd


path = '/My Documents/Python/'
fileName = "Test.xlsx"


#ef = pd.ExcelFile(path+fileName)

df = pd.read_excel(path+fileName, 'Coded Data')
#writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path+fileName, options={'strings_to_urls': False})

i = 1
for test in df['Content']:
    try:
        df['Content'] = df['Content'].astype(str)
    except:
        print("An exception occurred")
        break
    i += 1

print('success')
df.to_excel('/My Documents/Python/test_NEW.xlsx')
print('success')
```

Thank you in advance! Looking forward to hearing from you.